# Storing grid data with stash

Tags: ee2, stash, grid, switch

I am using stash to store some common site data and would like to use a grid field to store one of the fields with the user having the option to input 0-4 rows. Is there a way to do this with stash?

So if I was stashing the variables is there anything I use like the switch statement with stash?

Something like:

```
{grid_field}
    {exp:stash:row_{switch='1|2|3|4'}_col_1}{grid_field:col_1}{/exp:stash:row_{switch='1|2|3|4'}_col_1}
    {exp:stash:row_{switch='1|2|3|4'}_col_2}{grid_field:col_2}{/exp:stash:row_{switch='1|2|3|4'}_col_2}
{/grid_field}
```

Answer (score 1):

WOW! I'm an idiot. lol

I read right past the lists in the docs. Thanks for a great add on and doc set Mark.  ;)

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Lists

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="mini_links" parse_tags="yes"}
    {mini_links}
        {stash:href}{mini_links:link}{/stash:href}
        {stash:text}{mini_links:title}{/stash:text}
    {/mini_links}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Then:

```
<nav id="sub-menu">
    <ul>
        {exp:stash:get_list name="mini_links"}
            <li><a href="{href}">{text}</a></li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </ul>
</nav>
```